# "Неочевидна" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Слитно или раздельно следует писать "неочевидна".

> Нигде так неочевидна наша шаблонность, как в отношениях.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем предложении, конечно, раздельно. Отрицание налицо, причём усиленное усилительной приставкой/частицей НИ.